# React es6 and firebase loading data

Tags: reactjs, firebase

What is the "best practise" for loading firebase data into a react project when using ES6 syntax? the mixin isn't supported in es6 so the reactfire appears not to be an option

I have taken this approach, but it's really not elegant and I'd like to hear some possible solutions to how this could be done. this.items is declared as `this.items = []` within the constructor method

```
componentWillMount() {
        this.firebaseRef = new Firebase(SETTINGS.FIREBASEURL + 'todos');

        let self = this;
        this.firebaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
            self.items.push(snapshot.val());
            self.setState({data: self.items});
        });
    }

componentDidMount() {
        let self = this;

        let intVal = setInterval(function() {
            if (self.items.length > 0){
                self.setState({data: self.items});
                self.forceUpdate();
                clearInterval(intVal);
            }
        }, 200);
    }

componentWillUnmount() {
        this.firebaseRef.off();
}

render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return <p>Hello, Kitty</p>;
}
```

When I load this into a browser I the data being updated twice. How to I avoid having to use the `forceUpdate()` to display my `state.data`?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything in `componentDidMount()`. Whenever a child is added, you already call `setState()`, which will update the components in the UI. If that's not working, can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that shows them problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this from the React site: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#mixins.

For now it looks like you will have to use older syntax in this particular case!

For the updating question, check out the componentShouldUpdate method of the lifecycle. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: Yeah, I saw the documentation earlier but thought there must be away to do this. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I just started looking into this same question, and all the other answers I've come across point to this alternative:

https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base

From the author:

> The problem with ReactFire is because it uses Mixins, it's not compatible with ES6 classes. After chatting with Jacob Turner, we wanted to create a way to allow the one way binding of ReactFire with ES6 classes along some more features like two way data binding and listening to Firebase endpoints without actually binding a state property to them. Thus, re-base was built.